# css not working unless I inspect the style sheet and make a change

Tags: html, css, nginx

I have a webpage with a CSS stylesheet.

The stylesheet on the page does not work when loaded, but if I inspect the element and make a change to the css in the dev tools, it then displays properly.
I can change it, and change it back—and it works, I can adjust a value by 1, I can add a space somewhere or even just a new line at the bottom.

With the troubleshooting done I don't think it could be the stylesheet as I change nothing just inspect and hit enter and it works. I have deleted and re-created the page, moved it, copied it, etc and the only thing that makes it display is any minor edit of the stylesheet.

Same in Chrome and Firefox. The links also react the same so it does not seem to be just the index.html.

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
}
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 5px;
}
.center2 {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.center_img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 30%;
}
.base{
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 15%;
  height: auto;
  widht: auto;
}
.div_log {
  margin-left: 15%;
}
aside {
  color: #fff;
  width: 14%;
  min-width: 150px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(30deg , #0048bd, #44a7fd);
  border-top-right-radius: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
}

aside a {
  font-size: 19px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent;
}

aside a:hover {
  color: #3f5efb;
  background: #fff;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}

aside a i {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

aside a:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  bottom: 100%;
  right: 0;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 0 0 #fff;
}

aside a:hover::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  top: 38px;
  right: 0;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  border-top-right-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: 0 -20px 0 0 #fff;
}

aside p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 40px 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
bgimage {
  background-image: url("/images/int.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto;
}

.social {
  height: 0;
}

.social i:before {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: fixed;
  color: #fff;
  background: #0077B5;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top:5px;
  right:5px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_sheet.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>
    <aside>
      <p> Menu </p>
      <a href="index.html">
        <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        Home
      </a>
      <a href="config.php">
        <i class="fa fa-gear" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        Configure Interface
      </a>
      <a href="sendpage.php">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        Send Message
      </a>
      <a href="input.php">
        <i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        View Log
      </a>
    </aside>

    <div class="base">
      <img src="images/MSMWelcome.jpg">
      </img>
      <div>
        <img src="images/int.png" class="img">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute path for the css file?

Comment: Yes, that did not help either. The page knows of the css file as I said if I inspect the sources and just edit the css minimally it loads until I refresh.

Comment: Possibly the style sheet is rendered from the cache. What happens when you refresh or do a hard refresh?

Comment: Same problem, different browsers, machines I had never used before, nothing seems to load the css. No errors in the console, as I said I inspect the page go to sources and the css page and if I edit it in any way it loads properly.

Comment: Except a minor typo in style sheet (`widht` instead of width) and an unnecessary `</img>` in HTML , it seems OK.  Rename the style sheet file and reload the page, just in case.

Comment: Another CSS typo: Your "bgimage" selector is missing the beginning period `.bgimage` to make it a class selector instead of an unknown type selector. Also, since you're not using XHTML, remove the forward slash at the end of your `link` tag. `<link />`

Answer (score 0):

I had found the answer on a page but I had to clear my cache and history so I cannot find the page to link it
add the lines

```
      include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
      sendfile on;
```

in my nginx.conf under my `http {` line

Comment: So the issue was with your server configuration regarding MIME types?